# Angular JS - Dynamic directive with default behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want the developer to be able to use a controller of his choosing when using a specific directive. How this is achieved is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647720/1279730

However, I additionally want to have a "default" behaviour, if no controller is set. In "concept" this could look like:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).
directive('addIcons', function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope:{},
    controller : function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
         // A default implementation
         var default = function () { $scope.name = "baz"; }

         // return the controller which handles this "request"
         return $attr.controllerName ? $attr.controllerName : default;
    },
    template:'<input type="button" value="(+) plus" ng-click="add()">'
  }
})
```

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still add the controller name in the compile phase and it will be available like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).
    directive('communicator', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            template: "<input type='text' ng-model='message'/><input type='button' value='Send Message' ng-click='sendMsg()'><br/>",
            controller: "@",
            name: "controllerName",
            compile: function (tElements, tAttributes) {
                tAttributes.controllerName = tAttributes.controllerName || "LandlineCtrl"
                return;
            }
    }})
```