# Angular Controller on Custom Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my `controllers.js` file

```
(function(ctx,angular){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.controllers')

    .controller('SearchMasterController',['$scope',function($scope){
        //My Code
    }]);

})(window, angular);
```

And this is my `directives.js` file

```
(function(ctx,angular){
    function ControllerFunction(){
        //My Controller Code
    }
    var directiveConfig = {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'path/to/acco.html',
        controller: ControllerFunction
    }

    angular.module('app.directives')
    .directive('acco', function(){
        return directiveConfig;
    });
})(window, angular);
```

Now my question is, can I use this `acco` directive with some different controller. Ideally, is there any way to get it working like

`<acco ng-controller="SearchMasterController"></acco>` ?

I tried doing,

```
<acco>
    <div ng-controller="SearchMasterController"></div>
</acco>
```

and it seems to work.

Is it possible to use

`<acco ng-controller="SearchMasterController"></acco>` ?

The latter alternative looks ugly to me.

Comment: check this one :                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives

Answer (score 1):

nice to heard this type of access, i have tried

```
<acco>hi{{name1}}
    <div ng-controller="SearchMasterController">{{name1}}</div>
</acco>
<acco ng-controller="SearchMasterController">{{name1}}</acco>
<script>
            angular.module('myApp', [])
                    .controller('SearchMasterController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                            //My Code
                            console.log("search");
                            $scope.name1 = 'james';
                        }])
                    .directive('acco', function () {
                        return{
                            restrict: 'E',
                            templateUrl: 'acco.html',
                            controller: function($scope) {
                                //My Controller Code
                                console.log("cntrlr fn");
                                $scope.name1 = 'semaj';
                            }
                        };
                    });
</script>
```

@that time i getting output as

```
cntrlr fn
search
cntrlr fn
```

means if we are using like

```
<acco>hi{{name1}}
    <div ng-controller="SearchMasterController">{{name1}}</div>
</acco>
```

then we can access both controllers but when we are using like

```
<acco ng-controller="SearchMasterController">{{name1}}</acco>
```

we can't access SearchMasterController and it's not loaded also..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use some different controller for your directive, but there is some [best practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)

> Use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

The way you tried to use controller doesn't make much sense

```
<!--here acco and ng-controller both are directives,
    in your directive's 'ControllerFunction' and ng-controller's 'SearchMasterController'
    has the same controll (scope) for 'acco' rendered html.
    In that case your directive's controller overrite ng-controller functionality.
    So leave 'ng-controller',
    if you need any functionality in your directive
    then pass those functionality using =,&,@-->

<acco ng-controller="SearchMasterController"></acco>
```