# Sharing directive isolated scope with dynamic controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm writing a TypeScript AngularJS application and have hit a wall. I need to dynamically apply a controller to a directive since this directive provides a dynamic UI to accommodate different tasks. I need to be able to dynamically substitute in a controller to handle different activities in the directive.

I found information at [How to set the dynamic controller for directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives) that answers how to do this giving me the following:

```
export interface IHostScope extends ng.IScope {
  type: string;
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
}

export class Host implements ng.IDirective {
  public templateUrl: "/some/template/url";
  public restrict: "E";
  public replace: true;
  public controller = "@";
  public name = "controllerName";
  public scope: Object {
    type: "@",
    title: "@",
    subtitle: "@"
  };
  public link: Function = (scope: IHostScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes): void => {
    //Stuff happens in here
  }
}

export class ControllerA {
  constructor(private: $scope: IHostScope, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
    //$scope and $state are null at runtime
  }
}


module.directive("host", <any>Host);
module.controller("ControllerA", ControllerA);
```

The problem is that at runtime, the $state and $scope values are null and I have no way to access existing properties on each of these variables that might have been set by the link function on the directive. How can I share the scope between the directive and the dynamic controller and get the $state to actually populate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I posted this, I realized that the answer is quite simple. I need to inject the services into the controller and it resolves itself.

At the top of the ControllerA before the constructor add the $inject statement like:

```
export class ControllerA {
  static $inject = ["$scope", "$state"];
  constructor(private $scope: IHostScope, private $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
    //Do stuff - works like a charm
  }
}
```