# Dynamic controller bindings for component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use dynamic controller binding like in directives? I'm trying achieve the same behaviour for Angular 1.5 Components.

Directive example

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).

directive('addIcons', function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope:{},
    controller : "@",
    name:"controllerName",    
    template:'<input type="button" value="(+) plus" ng-click="add()">'
  }
}).
controller("IconsOneCtrl",function($scope){
     $scope.add = function(){
        alert("IconsOne add ");
      }
}).
controller("IconsTwoCtrl",function($scope){
     $scope.add = function(){
        alert("IconsTwo add ");
      }
});
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives

Comment: @timsmiths thanks for quick reply. But I tried it before posting the question. Even I added the Directive example.. This is angular 1.5 component, not directives.