# Dynamic controller for directives with ECMA6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set a controller dynamically to my directive using the `name` property. So far this is my code.

html

```
<view-edit controller-name="vm.controller" view="home/views/med.search.results.detail.resources.audios.html" edit="home/views/med.media.resources.edit.html"></view-edit>
```

js

```
export default class SearchResultsCtrl extends Pageable {

  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($injector, $state, api) {

    super(
      {
        injector: $injector,
        endpoint: 'mediaMaterialsList',
        selectable:{
          itemKey: 'cid',
          enabled:true,
          params: $state.params
        },
        executeGet: false
      }
    );

    this.controller = SearchResultsResourcesAudiosCtrl;
  }
}
```

Directive

```
export default class ViewEditDirective {

  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'E';
    this.replace = true;
    this.templateUrl = 'home/views/med.view.edit.html';
    this.scope = {};
    this.controller = "@";
    this.name = "controllerName";
    this.bindToController = {
      'view': '@?',
      'edit': '@?'
    };

    this.open = false;
    this.controllerAs = 'ctrl';
  }
}
```

I get `undefined` for `vm.controller`. I guess that it's rendering before the controller can assign the controller to the variable (I debbuged it, and it's setting the controller in the variable).

I'm following this answer to achieve this, but no luck so far.
[How to set the dynamic controller for directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to ES6 (which is a sugar syntax coating over ES5), this is how Angular scope life cycle works.

This directive may show what's the deal with attribute interpolation

```
// <div ng-init="a = 1"><div sum="{{ a + 1 }}"></div></div>
app.directive('sum', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($attrs) {
      console.log($attrs.sum) // {{ a + 1 }}
      // ...
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.sum) // 2
    }
  };
});
```

And `$attrs.sum` may still not be `2` in `link` if `a` value was set after that (i.e. in parent directive `link`).

It is unsafe (and wrong per se) to assume that the value on one scope can be calculated based on the value from another scopes at some point of time. Because it may be not. That is why watchers and data binding are there.

All that `controller: '@'` magic value does is getting [uninterpolated attribute value](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.1/src/ng/compile.js#L2488) and using it as controller name. So no, it won't interpolate controller name from `vm.controller` and will use 'vm.controller' string as controller name.

An example of a directive that allows to set its controller dynamically may look like

```
// dynamic-controller="{{ ctrlNameVariable }}"
app.directive('dynamicController', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 2500,
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $interpolate, $compile) {
            var ctrlName = $interpolate($attrs.dynamicController)($scope);

            setController(ctrlName);
            $attrs.$observe('dynamicController', setController);

            function setController (ctrlName) {
                if (!ctrlName || $attrs.ngController === ctrlName) {
                    return;
                }

                $attrs.$set('ngController', ctrlName);
                $compile($element)($scope);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

with all the side-effects that re-compilation may bring.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try this as soon as I get to the office tomorrow. Another question. If I pass the name of the controller directly, I wouldn't need to interpolate, right? Like doing `<view-edit controller-name="SearchResultsResourcesAudiosCtrl" view="home/views/med.search.results.detail.resources.audios.html" edit="home/views/med.media.resources.edit.html"></view-edit>`

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker Yes, this should work as is, that's the purpose of `controller: '@'`.