# How to set dynamic controller in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to specify the name of the controller, to be used with the directive, through a variable passed as a directive attribute by the parent controller.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives) post, and prepared the below directive.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('parent', function($scope) {
  $scope.scopeVar = 'child';
})

.controller('child', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'Hello';
})

.directive('myDir', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    template: '<div>Message: {{msg}}</div>',
    controller: '@',
    name: 'controllername'
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parent">
  <my-dir controllername="{{scopeVar}}"></my-dir>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the `controllername` attribute's value is being treated as a string, and not being resolved into the required value.

That is if we hard code

```
<my-dir controllername="child">
```

instead of

```
<my-dir controllername="{{scopeVar}}">
```

it works (but that's not what I want)