# Angularjs / How to Dynamically set controller for component

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('App').component('simpleTable', {
  controller: placeHolderForCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'components/simpleTable/simpleTableTemplate.html'
});
```

//usage

```
   <simple-table controller-name='nameofmyCtrltoSend'></simple-table>
```

Comment: Are you using an own directive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the dynamic controller for directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444414/how-to-set-the-dynamic-controller-for-directives)